# Amazon EC2 EBS volume scheduled backup/snapshots using puppet / similar tools

Tags: backup, amazon-ec2, cron, puppet, amazon-ebs

I am not a Linux admin, although I wish I was, and I have seen these questions

- [Amazon EC2 Backup Strategy](https://serverfault.com/questions/316795/amazon-ec2-backup-strategy)
- [Amazon EC2 + EBS:: Regular backup plan?](https://serverfault.com/questions/249711/amazon-ec2-ebs-regular-backup-plan)
- [Simple Backup Strategy for Amazon EC2 instances / volumes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/136412/simple-backup-strategy-for-amazon-ec2-instances-volumes)

And this suggestion 
http://alestic.com/2009/09/ec2-consistent-snapshot

I tried using command line + crontab (the command line works, but crontab for some reason, doesn't)

But I'm still pretty lost, **all I want is an automated, rolling backup of my amazon EC2 (EBS)** data

(by rolling I mean keep 3-4 weeks back, but delete old snapshots as new ones come for cost control)

And as things usually go, if there is something that is hard and painful, someone creates a solution for it.

My question is simple, is there a way using a tool like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/solutions/ec2/) to do it without a painful learning curve?

(or via other tools like http://ylastic.com)

If yes, how?

Comment: Take a look at Skeddly http://www.skeddly.com for automated, rolling EBS snapshots.  (Disclaimer, I am associated with this product)

Comment: @MattHouser please put this as an answer, it fits the question (I modified it to be less specific) and exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I created PHP based script and easy to install instruction. It will create backups and delete old. Fully configurable. http://serverfault.com/questions/237246/automate-amazon-ebs-snapshot-creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Skeddly](http://www.skeddly.com) for automated, rolling EBS snapshots.

Disclaimer, I am associated with this product

Answer (score 1):

Puppet isn't a backup solution, although you could use Puppet to deploy, configure, and maintain a backup solution. This could be as simple as scripts that use the EC2 API command line tools and cron (not sure what problem you had here, but it certainly could be done this way). Or use the AWS SDK for whatever programming language you prefer.

It sounds like Ylastic or a service for this would suit you best. Ylastic works for us. We use EC2 tags for volumes we want to snapshot and Ylastic handles the rest (including rolling backups).

Answer (score 1):

Create a script which uses "ec2-consistent-snapshot" and add it to crontab to run once a day (or any suitable interval).

To remove old snapshots use "ec2-describe-snapshots" and check the date to remove old snapshots.

Comment: yes, tried it, no matter what I do, the crontab doesn't run, and as I said I'm not a linux Admin, and simply couldn't find out why (checked the logs, tried different users / paths, nothing), I know that with enough time I will figure it out, but I was looking for something that will spare me that...

Comment: Where are you setting the needed env variables? Have you checked so all env variables that is needed to run ec2 cmd tools are set when rc.local is run. I usually create a script file which sets all needed env variables and then lets rc.local call that script.